# ajax loading on edit toolbar causing seriously annoying behaviour

Tags: support, editor

OK so today I started to hit edit on peoples questions and I notice:

- The toolbar on the top is first disabled.
- Then the preloader (same one that shows for the tags etc) shows up.

**Then**

The page kinda reloads and my **caret** gets places in the title.

So everytime I hit edit, I start editing the question and a second or two later my caret is in the title box and whatever I just typed replaces the title.

This is very annoying as I've had to return to the question and then hit edit, wait for the loading and then start editing quite a few times, till I got frustrated and decided to post here.

Might not be too useful but here is a screenie anyway :
[image]

Note, how the toolbar is disabled.

I'm on Google Chrome 10 + Windows 7 x64

Comment: whopsies, updated question =)

Comment: Right-clicking, selecting "inspect element" anywhere on the page, will get you the web inspector. Opening its Network tabsheet and then refreshing the page might show some resource that fails to load, or is extremely slow to load? (No issues in Chrome 10 on a Mac, here.)

Comment: oh? I thought this was a _new feature_. Post-loading the edit bar for some vague reason. I'll do more research and get back here.

Comment: Might sound silly - are you logged in when it happens?

Comment: @shadow yes I am logged in. like I said, me thought the preloader was by design.. will try on my laptop tomrw morning and add an update..

Comment: Weird, the only time I see the "preloader" is when focusing the edit area while not logged in then it's loading the "Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow! This is a Q&A site,..." message however it does not set focus to the title.

Comment: @giddy, maybe it helps investigating: do you have the same issue when editing other people's *answers*? And what about editing *your own* posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supposed to happen; the loading of the editor being delayed until the text box is focused should *only* happen for anonymous users when viewing a question.

The way this is implemented is that the file `wmd.js` just isn't included in the page itself; the JavaScript then checks if the function `editorReady` exists (this function is provided by `wmd.js`). Only if this function isn't there, the whole "disabled" thing happens.

My guess is that there's a bug in Chrome 10 that causes the check for `editorReady` to happen *before* that object is available (which shouldn't happen, based on the order of stuff in the page).

<s>So unless someone can reproduce this with a released browser, I'm inclined to consider this a bug in a beta browser.</s> Never mind that – the fact that Chrome 10 was released went past me somehow. I'm still sure this is a Chrome bug, but since it's an officially supported browser, we'll investigate.

Comment: *based on the order of stuff in the page* — unfortunately no time to investigate right now (and I am NO expert!), but in 2008 IE8 introduced a scary [parallel script loading](http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/?ex=3&title=IE8+Parallel+Script+Loading). I've never investigated what happens when such external script includes code that is (to be) executed right away. (Like code outside a function definition.) Maybe Chrome 10 has introduced some parallel thingy too, and has somehow taken it a step further? That said, I do NOT have this issue when logged in, nor in incognito mode, in Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: @Arjan: Yeah, that's my thought as well. And yes, I've seen similar problems in IE; e.g. if you trigger an event at the end of some JavaScript file, the stuff from said JS file isn't yet available to the handler bound to that event; you have to go through a 1ms timeout. Annoying.

Comment: So this is status-norepro for me and several people I know on Chrome 10 ...

Comment: [I want a diamond too](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/829597#829597)!

Comment: =( jeez I'm at work on my laptop (Win7+Chrome10) now and its all good! The edit toolbar appears ^pop^, neatly, just like before. I haven't rechecked at the desktop PC I was on last night! @balpha sorry for the trouble. I thought it was some new fangled feature and when it got just t0o annoying I slapped it here! =)